# No HttpSession currently exists, No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

The application working fine in local machine, but in the server facing auto Session timeout.

```
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No HttpSession currently exists
02:45:03.270 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
02:45:03.270 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /web/filerequeststransactionses/?page=3&size=10 at position 2 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
02:45:03.270 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /web/filerequeststransactionses/?page=3&size=10 at position 3 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
02:45:03.270 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /web/filerequeststransactionses/?page=3&size=10 at position 4 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
02:45:03.270 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /web/filerequeststransactionses/?page=3&size=10 at position 5 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
02:45:03.271 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /web/filerequeststransactionses/?page=3&size=10 at position 6 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
02:45:03.271 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /web/filerequeststransactionses/?page=3&size=10 at position 7 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
02:45:03.271 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@6faa3d44: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@ffff4c9c: RemoteIpAddress: 10.92.0.136; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
02:45:03.271 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /web/filerequeststransactionses/?page=3&size=10 at position 8 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
```

[using these properties in pom.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MBA0.png)

Comment: You should show your security configuration also

Answer (score 0):

You may be ambiguating the server anonymous session (going to the site) with an actual logged in session with the server.
Either way you can create an http session and as the error says it creates one anyhow on the first visit.
How are the session objects kept.
May be a glitch of domain at how you associate keeping sessions in your test localhost.
Or it may be some reliance by the server on cookies and the domain path in it(perhaps that says localhost when it should been changed in the cookie - e.g. configuration xml).